# In how many ways can $6$ students be selected from a group of $8$ if two brothers may not be selected together?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Find the number of ways of selecting $6$ students from a group of $8$ if Ah Chye and his brother must not be chosen together.

I tried $8C6$, but I don't know how to not choose Ah Chye and his brother.

Comment: There are two possibilities.  Neither Ah Chye nor his brother are chosen or one of the two brothers is selected along with five of the other six students.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting this as Ah Chye (one student) plus his brother, and another 6 arbitrary students.

Performing $_8C_6$ is all the ways to choose 6 students from the 8, leaving a multitude of ways for Ah Chye to be picked *with* his brother. There are 3 disjoint cases to consider:

1. Ah Chye is picked for the group. This means that his brother was not chosen. Since we've already chosen 1 student for the group, there are 5 remaining spots, and 6 children to fill them (since we used Ah Chye and can't use his brother). This can be done in $_6C_5$ ways.
2. Ah Chye's brother is picked for the group. This means that we can't also choose Ah Chye, and we have the same number as case 1: $_6C_5$.
3. Neither Ah Chye nor his brother were chosen. Since we haven't picked *any* group members yet, there are still 6 available spots, and 6 students need to fill them. There is only 1 way to choose 6 from 6 (choosing all of them).

Thus the total number of ways to choose 6 from 8, if Ah Chye can't be chosen with his brother is the sum of these disjoint cases: $2\cdot _6C_5 +1$

Comment: Another method is to subtract those committees in which both brothers are selected from the total.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**  We consider cases, depending on whether neither brother is selected or exactly one of the brothers is selected.

*Neither brother is selected*:  All six of the selected students must be selected from the six students other than Ah Chye and his brother.  This can be done in

> $$\binom{6}{6}$$

ways.

*Exactly one of the brothers is selected*:  We must choose one of the two brothers and five of the other six students, which can be done in

> $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{5}$$

ways.

*Total*:  Since the two cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of ways six students can be selected if Ah Chye and his brother are not selected together is

> $$\binom{6}{6} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{5}$$

**Method 2:**  We subtract the number of selections in which Ah Chye and his brother are both selected from the total number of ways of selecting six students.

As you found, there are 
$$\binom{8}{6}$$
ways to choose six of the eight students.

If Ah Chye and his brother are both selected, then four of the other six students must be selected, which can be done in

> $$\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{4}$$

ways.

Hence, the number of ways of selecting six of the eight students without selecting both Ah Chye and his brother is

> $$\binom{8}{6} - \binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{4}$$